# Leading zero in date select variable

Tags: php

I have a for loop to add the option tags in a select tag.

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++): ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $i ?>" <?php if(isset($post["date_birth"]['day']) && $post["date_birth"]['day'] == $i ) echo 'selected="selected"' ?>><?php echo $i ?></option>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

How can i add a leading zero to the numbers below 10?
at the moment i use a if statement, but i think thats not the good solution in a view

Comment: Where's the `IF` statement you mentioned? I'd think an `IF` statement would be okay solution here.

Comment: @MLeFevre this is code inside a ZF2 view. In my opinion I need to avoid using if statements inside those views as much as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sprintf for this

```
$s = sprintf("%02d", $i);
```

For more information, refer to the documentation of [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf).

Comment: thanks a lot! quick question: is it best to use `<?php echo...` or `<?=` in a view

Comment: either of the two would do. But for me personally I used <?=

Answer (score 2):

Use `str_pad`.

```
echo str_pad($i, 2 , "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

See: [str_pad()](https://www.php.net/str_pad)